# What macros are available .editorconfig's file_header_template?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, macros, editorconfig

I do know that `{filename}` macro refers to the actual file name in a .editorconfig's `file_header_template`. I am wondering if is there any other macro utility?

I would like to insert the current year for example.

Comment: Did you ever get any answers to this? I've been looking for documentation and not finding it anywhere.